# avoiding circular dependency in MVC.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, circular-reference

I have a bit off a problem with my project references as shown below
First you have the standard layer model and a MVC.NET project on top but then the red lines begin to come in play:

```
Resources -> used for creating and editing resource files (.resx) and 
saving information about them to the database.

Utility -> has some custom attributes that go on top of the model objects.
```

Resources needs Model because the Resource project saves a model object to the database.
`Model` needs `Utility` because of the custom attributes.

`Utility` needs `Resources` because it has to get the correct errormessages in the correct language form the the `Resources.ResourceManager`

NOT PICTURED: `MVC Web` uses the `Utility` library too

Problem: Model, Utility and Resources form a circular dependency which is impossible, any suggestions on how to fix the structure so it does work?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: example code from a `Utility` class, the `ResourceManager` comes from the Resource library:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
{
    ErrorMessage = ResourceManager.Get(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Lang(), ErrorMessageKey);


    ModelClientValidationRule CRequiredRule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
    CRequiredRule.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
    CRequiredRule.ValidationType = "crequired";

    yield return CRequiredRule;
}
```

[image: project structure]

Comment: And... what is the problem you want to ask? Include [mcve] for current implementation with your idea.

Comment: Utility should not get the translations, just use the resource keys and localize them in upper levels.

Comment: If it really is a `Utility` then why does it have to reference `Resources`? Or if it really needs to, then use `Resources` in `Utility` and then make a wrapper around `Resources` in your `Utility`. Kind of shitty idea but still better than nothing.

Comment: @m.rogalski added some example code

Comment: @JanneMatikainen added some exple code from the Utility

Comment: What I tend to do when it comes to n-tier application development is to make each layer have it's own "model" objects that extends base flat model from DAL. In your situation, I would suggest the same approach and in case of Utility and Resources, I would go with the key to value utility method. It would ask Utility for the resource Key ( without the need to reference Resource ). This key would be then passed to Resources to retrieve the adequate value. But still, the question remains the same. Why do you use Utility to get the value from Resources?

Comment: @m.rogalski `Resources` holds all the translations form every key, every project that needs a translation form a key needs to ask `Resources` for it.

Comment: @lordvlad30 Okay, that I understand. What I don't understand, why do you need Utility then? Since all you want to do is to grab translated text, then just get that from the Resources.

Comment: @m.rogalski Utilty has validation attributes that go on top off the models (in ´MVC web and in Model´) so it cannot be in either on of these projects, it has to be in a different ´Utility´ project

Comment: For me, it sounds like that 'Resources' is the problem. Why is Resources trying to save stuff to the DB? Shouldn't that be in the DAL? I don't see any reason for 'Resources' to depend on 'Model'.

Comment: @Dr.Coconut I'm now trying to split the Resources up and see where I can go from there

Comment: Looking at that diagram the problem is Utility should be a just that a utility class. The point of the Service Layer is to 'service' the other layers. SO your Service layer should be making the request to utility on behalf of all other layers. Depending on what is requested, utility may request from resources. Where utility isn't required, then Service should hook straight into resources to feed the other layers. Models should not need resources, however I can see that viewmodels might, if your using text decorators, but again it should be one way reference.

Comment: Solved it the ugly way: split the resourceManger class and merged most of it with the model. ugly and the model is not really the place for a repository of language resources but hell, I wasted a day on this. thanks everybody for the help and suggestions.